# Limits for Force.com One App User license

Tags: limits, licenses, community

From the help documentation i understand that there is limit of 10 customs objects for Force.com One App user license.

Is there any limit on the number of custom fields per each custom object ?

Advance thanks

Answer (score 3):

http://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf

Page 17 onwards

Do you know what Edition you are running